# PyBind11: simple invoke task, standard C++ library not found

Tags: python, c++, path, invoke, pybind11

i am trying to wrap the C++ library `PyrochloreAFM.hpp` which itself uses the lib `boost/randoom.hpp` so that i can import it as a python module. The C++ part itself works fine and i can succesfully import and use all of this from my main.

```
#include "PyrochloreAFM.hpp"
    
int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {
     PyrochloreAFM pyrochloreAFM (&parameters, &statistics, &rng);
}
```

Now following a tutorial i set up my c++ wrapper:

```
// pybind11_wrapper.cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <PyrochloreAFM.hpp>

PYBIND11_MODULE(pybind11_example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // Optional module docstring
    m.def("cpp_function", &PyrochloreAFM, "A function that multiplies two numbers");
}
```

and my tasks.py file

```
# tasks.py
import invoke

invoke.run(
    "g++ -O3 -Wall -Werror -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC PyrochloreAFM.cpp "
    "-o libpyro.so "
)
```

However now `$invoke build-PyrochloreAFM` or even `$invoke --list` seem to have lost the track of the standard C++ library.

```
In file included from PyrochloreAFM.cpp:1:
./Parameters.hpp:16:10: fatal error: 'boost/random.hpp' file not found
#include "boost/random.hpp" // tested with boost 1.53
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

This might be a simple PATH problem so i would be very glad for any tips!

Thank you, Andres!

Comment: Boost is **not** part of the C++ standard library, so you need to instruct your compiler to use it (for both include paths and linkage). Go to boost.org and check out the usage instructions.

Comment: You are totally right. Adding the flag "-I /opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.80.0/include" did it! Thank you! Post as answer if you seek the upvotes :)

Comment: Great. Now that you've found the solution, consider making it an answer yourself for future readers!

Answer (score 2):

"Of course" the `tasks.py` file which compiles the `.cpp` file through the python module `invoke` has to instruct the compiler `g++` to use the libraries we desire. In my case it is the flag `-I /opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.80.0/include` i also use in my `makefile` or directly in terminal.